# Using PHP template engine on Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

im calling `v-for` event on div tag to create `<a>` tag by every object on `results` array

Code attempt:

results array:

[image: result data]

html (Laravel blade):

```
@verbatim
    <div class="category-item" v-for="result in results" :value="result.id">
    <a class="button-product-info-s" href="/product/{{ result.id }}"/>{{ result.name }}</a>
    </div>
@endverbatim
```

brower output:

[image]

**as you can see `{{ result.name }}}` is just working and `{{ result.id }}` is not outputing anything**

i tried using `.{{ result.id }}.` but didn't work

Comment: Does the `:value="result.id"` work?

Comment: @Kabelbaan yes it does

Comment: Have you tried changing your href attribute to `:href="'/product/'.result.id"`? Or with the + operator instead of .

Comment: Check your error console. IIRC, Vue now refuses to do variable interpolation in HTML attributes.

Comment: @Kabelbaan thank you please answer this question and get credit for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing your href attribute to `:href="'/product/'.result.id"`?

Or with the + operator instead of .

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to something like:

```
@verbatim
    <div class="category-item" v-for="result in results" :value="result.id">
    <a class="button-product-info-s" href="/product/@{{ result.id }}"/>@{{ result.name }}</a>
    </div>
@endverbatim
```

Comment: if you use ```@verbatim```  you don't have to prefix each Blade echo statement with an ```@``` symbol